# How to convert hexadecimal array to decimal and back again in C?

Tags: c, hex

I have got a hexadecimal array, which I want to convert to decimal, do a modulus operation, and then convert it back to hexadecimal.

```
int main()
{
    char num[] = {0x02,0x03,0x04};
    long n = strtol(num, NULL, 16);
    printf("n=%ld\n", n);  
}
```

I am getting "0" here while I am expecting "262914".

EDIT:

I know that putting `char num[] = "0x040302"` will give me the expected output, but it needs to be withing the {} like `{0x02,0x03,0x04}`

Comment: Take a look at the ASCII table. `0x02`, `0x03` and `0x04` aren't what you may think.

Comment: `num` just contains three byte values 0x02, 0x03 and 0x04. But `strtol` expects a null-terminated (typically ASCII) string. If you replace `char num[] = {0x02,0x03,0x04};` with `char num[] = "20304"; then it should work, but probably isn't what you want.

Comment: The content of your char array, translated via ASCII table, is "STX", "ETX", "EOT". Also it is missing a null termination. Please explain your expectation. The 0 you get is easily explained, referring to e.g. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol and the description of the return value there.

Comment: By the way "The question does not show any research effort..." is textbook reason for downvoting. To avoid that, please describe how your research missed the specification of the used function.

Comment: @IanAbbott: I have tried that, but it needs to be like in the snippet {0x02,0x03,0x04}

Comment: Why do you expect `"262914"`?

Comment: Please explain your expectation. How is "262914" reasoned. While explaining please cover the difference of an array of char, interpreted as ASCII characters, and an array of char interpreted as a sequence of bytes. Mentioning the endianess behind the expaction might be helpful soon.

Comment: @Jabberwocky By doing it on hand, I get that. As one hexadecimal it is `0x040302`, and converting that to Base10 I get `262914`

Comment: The only way to get that result is far away from reading non-null-terminated array of char via strtol. Using strtol with your expected result seems to be an XY problem.

Comment: If you can do it by hand you can do it the same way in C.

Comment: Please explain your decision of using strtol, as opposed to `num[0]+256*num[1]+256*256*[num2]`, which I believe is how you do it "by hand". I.e. if you know how to do it, why don't you implement it like that?

Comment: I'd recommend using `unsigned char num[] = {0x02,0x03,0x04};` to avoid problems with sign extension. Then to get 262914, you can set `n = num[0] + ((long)num[1] << 8) + ((long)num[2] << 16);`. (The cast to `(long)` is there in case you have only 16-bit `int`.)

Comment: Do you know the difference between an integer literal in written in hexadecimal numbers and a string literal holding a hexadecimal number?

Answer (score 0):

> I know that putting char num[] = "0x040302" will give me the expected
>   output, but it needs to be withing the {} like {0x02,0x03,0x04}

"0x040302" is the equivalent of { '0', 'x', '0', '4', '0', '3', '0', '2', 0 },
or { 0x30, 0x78, 0x30, 0x34, 0x30, 0x33, 0x30, 0x32, 0x00 } assuming ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simply `num[0] + (num[1] << 8) + (num[2] << 16)`. In general, if `num` is `n` bytes long, then the answer is:

```
long i, r = 0;

for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    r += (long)(num[i]) << (8*i);
}
```

Of course make sure that `num` fits in a `long` (generally 4 or 8 bytes depending on your system).